# Does the word "situation" collocate with the word "main"?

Tags: word-choice, collocation

> Is it right to say "the main situation"?

I associate "main" with "problem".

Comment: GIYF.  What did you find?

Comment: @deadrat Oh the irony of having to Google _GYIF_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Don't worry. You're not the only one.

Answer (score 2):

"Main" is a widely used word and can modify many nouns. There is nothing grammatically wrong with "main situation", and there are many occasions in which it can be used.

If you are describing a current state, using "the main situation" is problematic because an entity can have only one "situation" at any time, just like it can have only one "state" or "condition". So it is wrong to say "the main situation I am in..." because you are only in one situation. You can of course have many problems, so it is fine to say "the main problem I have...".

But other uses of the phrase are fine. For example: "The main situation in which a fire extinguisher is useful is..."

Answer (score 1):

> When you describe something as **main**, you mean *it's the **most
>   important***, *well-known, or biggest of its kind.*

- The **main goal** of the first part of this book is to ...

  - **Main difficulties** faced ....
- The **main problems** in...

  - Cost is the **[main issue](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/main)** for many...

> There were three **[main situations](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=main%20situation&hl=en-IN&gbv=2&tbm=bks&ei=YOybVe2MDYb-8QXIiqiYBw&start=10&sa=N)** when the Eye-phone was used
>   .....